# CCMutableArray deprecated, how to change code

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am working through the cocos2d-x SimpleGame project, and I am stuck in chapter 5, http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_5_-_How_to_Detect_the_Collisions.

What I found is that CCMutableArray is deprecated in favor of CCArray. But how do I need to modify the following, to make it work with CCArray (which apparently does not support templates)?

HelloWorldScene.h

```
cocos2d::CCMutableArray<cocos2d::CCSprite*> *_projectiles;
```

HelloWorldScene.cpp

```
// in init()
// Initialize arrays
_projectiles = new CCMutableArray<CCSprite*>;

HelloWorld::~HelloWorld()
{
  if (_targets)
  {
    _projectiles->release();
    _projectiles = NULL;
  }
}

HelloWorld::HelloWorld()
:_projectiles(NULL)
{
}

void HelloWorld::update(float dt)
{
  CCArray *projectilesToDelete = new CCArray<CCSprite*>;
  CCMutableArray<CCSprite*>::CCMutableArrayIterator it, jt;

  for (it = _projectiles->begin(); it != _projectiles->end(); it++)
  {
     CCSprite *projectile = *it;
     // (...)
  }
  // (...)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is

```
CCArray* array1 = CCArray::create();
```

and later on to use it:

```
CCObject* arrayItem;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(array1, arrayItem){
    CCSprite* pItem = (CCSprite*)(arrayItem);
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: Thx, that really helped! And it's `new CCArray` instead of  `CCArray::create()` and `CCARRAY_FOREACH` instead of `CCARRAY_FOR_EACH`.

Comment: edited. but I think it might be better to use the create() static method and retain it, as the object will be autoreleased later without any problem. If using new CCArray() and when you finished using it, you have to manually release it.

Comment: using CCArray::create() got app crashing, instead i used "new CCArray" works fine.

Comment: @Faizan you shouldn't. you should use CCArray::create() and array->retain(). if you use new, you break the cocos2d-x memory management system, which means you need to delete the array manually.

Answer (score 0):

I use std::list<> instead, it works well.
just delete may some inefficient.

I'm cocos2d-x beginner yet, I don't know why they "re-inventing the wheel" (just in my beginner opinion) like CCMutableArray, CCArray... thing.

Comment: That is for porting the code from original cocos2d-iphone, to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

try to use std::vector it is good enough :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_container_(C%2B%2B)

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm